# validate html form with powershell

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

How can I validate this form with a powershell script into internet explorer?
https://idsapp.ulb.ac.be/pam/pamnetid.php

Comment: You mean javascript or powershell script? Browsers can't handle powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to validate data in HTML forms before submitting data to the server you need javascript. Powershell for form validation does not make any sense. The only validation you can obtain is on the user input for example, but nothing to do with forms submission.

Comment: $ie.Document.getElementById("institution").value = "ULB";
$ie.Document.getElementById("category").value = "1";
$ie.Document.getElementById("rollnumber").value = $matricule;
$ie.Document.getElementById("birth_day").value = $date1;
$ie.Document.getElementById("birth_month").value = $date2;
$ie.Document.getElementById("birth_year").value = $date3;
# Click the submit button
$ie.Document.getElementById("Continue").Click(); 
but the last line does'n work

Comment: Can you clarify which language you are using? It seems a mix between powershell and javascript...why are you using `;`? How do you get `$ie`?

Comment: the beginig of the script is:
$url = "https://idsapp.ulb.ac.be/pam/pamnetid.php";

$matricule = Read-Host "matricule "
Write-host "date de naissance"
$date1 = Read-Host "jour "
$date2 = Read-Host "mois "
$date3 = Read-Host "annee "

$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.navigate($url);

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true)
{
 Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000;
}

Comment: try: `$ie.Document.getElementById("yourformidthatseemsnotset").submit()`